# Having trouble to place 6 divs as a 2x3 vertical grid

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

I've been learning HTML and CSS for a week now and I started an online course. At the end of the first part of it I have to create a responsive portfolio page. I do not have any projects yet as you can tell so I decided to imagine that I have and I am struggling all day long to create a simple grid of the divs I have created. I want it to be 2 columns of 3 rows next to each other, probably with some spacing between each element. 
However the closest I got so far is to have those 6 elements one below each other. So can you help, please?

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5tyjbLa4/1/

Thank you in advance and if my coding style is horrible, please let me know so I can improve. As I mentioned, i only started a week ago to code after work.

```css
.responsive {
    font-family: inherit serif;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1400px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    
}

.responsive li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 420px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid coral;
    border-radius: 50px; 
}

.responsive li img {
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.responsive h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.grid-container h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.grid-container p {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
```

```html
<section class="responsive">
    <h2> My work so far/ My Portfolio</h2>
    <ul class="grid-container">
        <li class="img1"><img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="400px" style="margin-top: 20px" "border-radius: 30%">
            <h3>This is a photo of Jack Russell</h3>
            <p>I do not have portfolio projects yet but I do have a Jack Russell Terrier who I love so I decided to post photo of a JRT.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="img2"><img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="400px" style="margin-top: 20px" "border-radius: 30%">
            <h3>This is a photo of Jack Russell</h3>
            <p>I do not have portfolio projects yet but I do have a Jack Russell Terrier who I love so I decided to post photo of a JRT.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="img3"><img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="400px" style="margin-top: 20px" "border-radius: 30%">
            <h3>This is a photo of Jack Russell</h3>
            <p>I do not have portfolio projects yet but I do have a Jack Russell Terrier who I love so I decided to post photo of a JRT.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="img4"><img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="400px" style="margin-top: 20px" "border-radius: 30%">
            <h3>This is a photo of Jack Russell</h3>
            <p>I do not have portfolio projects yet but I do have a Jack Russell Terrier who I love so I decided to post photo of a JRT.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="img5"><img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="400px" style="margin-top: 20px" "border-radius: 30%">
            <h3>This is a photo of Jack Russell</h3>
            <p>I do not have portfolio projects yet but I do have a Jack Russell Terrier who I love so I decided to post photo of a JRT.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="img6"><img src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/jack-russel-terrier-dog-breed-pictures/2-face.jpg" width="400px" style="margin-top: 20px" "border-radius: 30%">
            <h3>This is a photo of Jack Russell</h3>
            <p>I do not have portfolio projects yet but I do have a Jack Russell Terrier who I love so I decided to post photo of a JRT.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox for a simple grid:

```
.grid-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container li{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked beautifully! I will study your code now because I really banged my head against the wall today not being able to create the same effect.

Comment: Here a complete guide to flexbox if you want to learn how to use it ;) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

An simple float alternative is:

```
.grid-container > li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But an cleaner alternative is using flex: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hi pls change like this,

```
 .responsive { height: auto; }
```